# Navigating Ruby source code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My main goal is to be able to understand the library/gem that I am using, fully. I tried reading the source code from start to finish on Github but it was really hard.

I thought a more enjoyable and more gentle stepping stone would just be to read the source code of each library/gem method as I use it.

For example I want to know how the `redirect_to` method in Ruby on Rails works:

1. How can I look up the source code for the `redirect_to` method?

   - I am aware that in pry I can do something like `show-method method`, but how can I do this for methods in the Rails framework?
2. Do you have any suggestions on how I can better understand gems and their APIs? Just reading the source code seems really hard, especially for frameworks.

Thank You!

Comment: "how can I do this for methods in rails framework" - exactly the same way. Methods are methods.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your response completely, are you suggesting I do this `show-method redirect_to` for example? If so I am not sure how I would go about loading the required modules into the pry session.

Comment: "how I would go about loading the required modules" - just do it in a rails console. Set a breakpoint (`binding.pry`) somewhere in controller, hit it (by visiting the corresponding url in your browser) and then do `show-source redirect_to`.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RubyMine IDE meets this need for me. It has these features which greatly lower the barrier to reading gem source:

- Gems are part of the project tree (in the External Libraries pseudo-directory), so you can navigate and even edit them just as you would your own code.
- A single key command (command-B on Mac) navigates from an identifier (module/class name, method name, etc.) to its declaration, or brings up a list to choose from if there are multiple declarations. It works for both your code and gem code.
- Another command (option-command-O on Mac) allows you to enter an identifier name to navigate to as above. It automatically includes library code if what you enter is not found in your code; if what you enter is found in your code, you can hit the keys once more to include gem code anyway.
- The debugger constantly displays the code you're executing. You can set a breakpoint without editing the code where you want it. You can inspect any stack frame above the one that is actually executing. All these features work equally well with your code and gem code.

In general RubyMine features all work with gem code as well as with project code.

Regarding methods of understanding gems other than reading their source code: Most gems are documented in their READMEs (which I invariably read on Github) and possibly other documentation files in the gem's root or in the doc directory. Some gems (the Rails gems included) have rdoc that is worth reading. However, since it's so convenient to navigate from use of a gem to its code, I usually try that first, and read the rdoc (if there is any) in the code before I read the actual code. RubyMine can also display the rdoc for an identifier where it's used (F1 on a Mac), but I've always found it easier to just go straight to the code.

Comment: Sounds great, I do remember features like that when I was using RubyMine IDE but unfortunately it is paid, and a broke college dropout like me can't afford something like that right now...

Comment: I think it's worth it if you're spending significant time programming. However, ways to use it free include the free trial, the [open source license](https://www.jetbrains.com/buy/opensource/) and winning a license in a user group/meetup raffle, which I have done three times!

Comment: ahah I will have a look then. And thanks for the tips with the IDE I will definitely revisit this if I ever get an IDE.

Comment: My +1 to rubymine and the rest of the tips. It's exactly what I do too.

Answer (score 2):

My first approach when trying to learn how to use a gem is to write tests against it.

Robert C. Martin writes :

> Learning the third-party code is hard. Integrating the third-party code is hard too.
>   Doing both at the same time is doubly hard. What if we took a different approach? Instead
>   of experimenting and trying out the new stuff in our production code, we could write some
>   tests to explore our understanding of the third-party code. Jim Newkirk calls such tests
>   learning tests.
>
> In learning tests we call the third-party API, as we expect to use it in our application.
>   We’re essentially doing controlled experiments that check our understanding of that API.
>   The tests focus on what we want out of the API.

Reading the source code comes after, when you are truly concerned of how the internals work.

Hope this helps!

As for where `redirect_to` is defined in ActionController::Redirecting

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb

Comment: I see thanks for the idea! I appreciate you giving me a direct answer but is there a methodical way in finding the source code for methods?

Comment: Alas, I don't have any methodical way.

Answer (score 2):

If you can get code into a controller this is often more informative:

```
raise method(:redirect_to).source_location.inspect
```

That will show you precisely where the method was defined.

When working with large code-bases like this I generally lean on `git` pretty hard:

```
git grep 'def redirect_to'
```

If that turns up nothing:

```
git grep 'redirect_to'
```

You may need to filter more carefully but often the implementation stands out visually.

The nice thing about Ruby code is it's *generally* quite readable and searching through it is often more pleasant than in other languages.